# i want to override file vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml in magento 2.3 porto theme

Tags: layout, overrides, xml, magento2.3.2, porto-theme

I am using smartwave porto theme in magneto 2.3.2.I am new in magento.How to override this above title file.
But I checked in app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/
In above path module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml  there is nothing like this.
Please not clear to me how to override this.

Answer (score 0):

To override `module-theme::default.xml` in your current theme :

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Comment: allready i have app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml  default.xml on this location.And this default.xml is diffrent..them how to merge on this .

Comment: in this case, just update the code that you need in path note above

Comment: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/reorder/sidebar.phtml
Now i want to overright this file
but app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Sales on this pathonly web and css path is exist...Then how to create and overright it..I thanks for above help

Comment: Pls can you share your mail id..I am very new to magento.If I need help then i will mail you..If your are free and willing to help .Thanks